# Symfony deploy PHP fatal error: Class not found in AppKernel.php

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, deployment, swiftmailer

So..
Ive been building an application with Symfony3 framework for my bachelor project and it works flawless on localhost. Both in dev-environment and prod.

However. When Im trying to deploy it to a Heroku App im getting the following log..

```
Generating optimized autoload files
   > Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
   Creating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
   > Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
   > Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle' not found in /tmp/build_68991520ff4642cdf86248159a2f0f54/Carante-getmoving-585074f/app/AppKernel.php:15
   Stack trace:
   #0 /tmp/build_68991520ff4642cdf86248159a2f0f54/Carante-getmoving-585074f/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(396): AppKernel->registerBundles()
   #1 /tmp/build_68991520ff4642cdf86248159a2f0f54/Carante-getmoving-585074f/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(114): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
   #2 /tmp/build_68991520ff4642cdf86248159a2f0f54/Carante-getmoving-585074f/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
   #3 /tmp/build_68991520ff4642cdf86248159a2f0f54/Carante-getmoving-585074f/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(118): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvI in /tmp/build_68991520ff4642cdf86248159a2f0f54/Carante-getmoving-585074f/app/AppKernel.php on line 15
   Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception


     [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
     An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
     PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle' not found in /tmp/build_68991520ff4642cdf86248159a2f0f54/Carante-getmoving-585074f/app/AppKernel.php:15                                                                                                                                                              
     Stack trace:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
     #0 /tmp/build_68991520ff4642cdf86248159a2f0f54/Carante-getmoving-585074f/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(396): AppKernel->registerBundles()                                                                                                                                                                                    
     #1 /tmp/build_68991520ff4642cdf86248159a2f0f54/Carante-getmoving-585074f/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(114): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()                                                                                                                                                        
     #2 /tmp/build_68991520ff4642cdf86248159a2f0f54/Carante-getmoving-585074f/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()                                                                                                                                                       
     #3 /tmp/build_68991520ff4642cdf86248159a2f0f54/Carante-getmoving-585074f/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(118): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvI in /tmp/build_68991520ff4642cdf86248159a2f0f54/Carante-getmoving-585074f/app/AppKernel.php on line 15  
     .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 


   install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...

!     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
!     Push failed
```

Or at least this is where it starts to go wrong.

My AppKernel.php file looks like this..

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

    class AppKernel extends Kernel
    {
        public function registerBundles()
        {
            $bundles = [
                new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
                new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
                new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
                new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
                new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
                new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
                new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
                new Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle(),
                new \Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle(),
                new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
            ];

            if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
                $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
                $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
                $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
                $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
                $bundles[] = new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle();
            }

            return $bundles;
        }
```

If I comment out the Swiftmailer class in AppKernel, another class is causing the exact same issue.

I hope theres someone here who can help me out or at least to understand the error a bit more.

Truth be told, deploying applications and handling anything serverside is not my strongest site so im in pretty deep water.

Thanks... :)

Comment: Have you looked at this at all: https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/heroku.html

Comment: Try after updating composer. that might be solve the issue

Comment: @AlvinBunk Yes i have gone through both the symfony tut and the heroku one, but it seems like I'm missing some configurations or something which i cannot figure out...?

Comment: @GopalJoshi That is what I stumbled upon now as well. But when Im updating i get the following error:
`Content-Length mismatch
http://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date`

Comment: please check permission of cache folder. Reference https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3470

Answer (score 0):

I'm beginning to think it's a file permission issue as well like Gopal. Here's the documentation on file permissions that need to be set:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html

Heroku is a bit different, so I don't have any guidance on that since I haven't tried it before.

Comment: I've commented your suggestion with an "answer"

Answer (score 0):

@AlvinBunk I've reensured the permissions in the various folders and established a much more stable internet connection and the previous composer update error is now gone..

However.. Now i get the same error as i do when I'm trying to deploy the app.

```
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception


  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                    
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:                                                                                                             
  Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "SwiftmailerBundle" from namespace "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle".        
  Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /Users/carante/KEA/WebDeveloping/3. Semester/Bachelor/Application/getmoving-fiji/app/AppKernel.php:16                      
  Stack trace:                                                                                                                                                                          
  #0 /Users/carante/KEA/WebDeveloping/3. Semester/Bachelor/Application/getmoving-fiji/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(396): AppKernel->registerBund  
  les()                                                                                                                                                                                 
  #1 /Users/carante/KEA/WebDeveloping/3. Semester/Bachelor/Application/getmoving-fiji/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(114): Symfony\Component\HttpK  
  ernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()                                                                                                                                                     
  #2 /Users/carante/KEA/WebDeveloping/3. Semester/Bachelor/Application/getmoving-fiji/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(68): Symfony\C  
  omponent\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()                                                                                                                                                    
  #3 /Users/carante/KEA/WebDeveloping/3. Semester/Bachelor/Application/getm in /Users/carante/KEA/WebDeveloping/3. Semester/Bachelor/Application/getmoving-fiji/app/AppKernel.php on l  
  ine 16                                                                                                                                                                                
  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "SwiftmailerBundle" from namespace "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle".   
  Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /Users/carante/KEA/WebDeveloping/3. Semester/Bachelor/Application/getmoving-fiji/app/AppKernel.php:16                      
  Stack trace:                                                                                                                                                                          
  #0 /Users/carante/KEA/WebDeveloping/3. Semester/Bachelor/Application/getmoving-fiji/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(396): AppKernel->registerBund  
  les()                                                                                                                                                                                 
  #1 /Users/carante/KEA/WebDeveloping/3. Semester/Bachelor/Application/getmoving-fiji/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(114): Symfony\Component\HttpK  
  ernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()                                                                                                                                                     
  #2 /Users/carante/KEA/WebDeveloping/3. Semester/Bachelor/Application/getmoving-fiji/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(68): Symfony\C  
  omponent\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()                                                                                                                                                    
  #3 /Users/carante/KEA/WebDeveloping/3. Semester/Bachelor/Application/getm in /Users/carante/KEA/WebDeveloping/3. Semester/Bachelor/Application/getmoving-fiji/app/AppKernel.php on l  
  ine 16                                                                                                                                                                                
  .
```

Comment: Have you contacted Heroku support? Or maybe you have a free account? I'm not sure how support works. I still suspect a file permissions problem.

Comment: So. It works now. I deleted and unhooked the swiftmailer bundle everywhere and i succesfully deployed. Afterwards i reenabled and isntalled the bundle again and It seemed like i had an issue with my bundle requirements.
I was trying to run
`composer require swiftmailer/swiftmailer`
Instead of using 
`composer require symfony/swiftmailer-bundle`

Thanks for your help though @AlvinBunk

Comment: You can help me by upvoting any one of my comments! Glad you got it working!